# How to predict output by balancing two parameters?

Tags: prediction

I have a lot of data with two parameters(in each row), and I need to balance the two factors so that the output quality factor, depends on these parameters. Each parameter has to contribute more or less equally to the resulting quality factor.

A case where one of the factor varies extremely from mean value of the population, it must have low quality factor.

For example, a packet is sent, it has two parameters as transfer time T, certainty of correctly receiving data C. I wish to get an quality factor for whole transfer(based on these two parameters), so that whenever two parameters are given I can predict its quality based on previous available values. (I had a similar use case, I tried to give weights manually and test on number of rows, but the results didn't prove to be good enough).

How could I improve my results ? (Any suggestions)

Comment: Sounds like a normal mathcase. (a + b) / 2 to get the avarage result. But before that calculation you could check whether a is higher than b or b is higher than a and then calculate the percentage of a to b or b to a. Followed by that you can say. Ok if the difference is more than 30% then kick the number out.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that is one good solution, will surely try that out. Is there any machine learning algorithm which might help? I don't know ML, I will learn and apply if it is helpful somehow.

Comment: Depends on what you want your machine to learn.

Comment: Machine should learn what are the good and bad parameters, to affect the output quality factor, for any new queries.

Comment: One parameter is probability and other is time (in sec). If I normalize the data, will it be suitable to take average? (I would like to balance the effect of these two parameters). Thanks.

Comment: Well don't bad parameters depend on the other parameter at that given point of time ? You can't really say that the number 1 is always bad for example. What you could do is do a few test runs and push the numbers that got kicked out into an array and see if you can find a pattern manually. If so you can programm the machine to find a pattern itself and exclude those numbers at all

Comment: Okay, thanks. Helped me a lot.